# Combining pyOSC with pyQT5 / Threading?

Tags: python, pyqt5

What I try to do:
I want to write a Python program running on an RPI which communicates to a software called QLab4 via OSC. It should display the received workspace data (JSON format) in a table, while the user is able to select a cue from the table and fire it using a key press.

So far I got two scripts (just proof of concept stage), but I struggle to combine them into one program. Any hints to how to do it would be greatly appreciated.

Script 1:
Starts OSC client & server and sends and receives OSC to/from QLAB.
At the moment it just prints out the JSON (workspace) and the selected cue.

```
import argparse
import time
import threading
import json

from pythonosc import udp_client
from pythonosc import dispatcher
from pythonosc import osc_server

workspace = {}
def print_json(unused_addr, args):
    global workspace
    workspace = json.loads(args)
    print(workspace)


def print_name(unused_addr, args):
    decoded_json = json.loads(args)
    print(args)
    print(type(decoded_json['data']))
    data = decoded_json['data']
    print("Cue Name: " + data['displayName'])
    print("Cue Number: " + data['number'])

def print_payload(unused_addr, args):
    print ("Selected Cue: " + args)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("--serverip", default="127.0.0.1", help="The ip to listen on")
    parser.add_argument("--serverport", type=int, default=53001, help="The port the OSC Server is listening on")
    parser.add_argument("--clientip", default="127.0.0.1", help="The ip of the OSC server")
    parser.add_argument("--clientport", type=int, default=53000, help="The port the OSC Client is listening on")
    args = parser.parse_args()


    # listen to addresses and print changes in values
    dispatcher = dispatcher.Dispatcher()
    dispatcher.map("/reply/workspace/C936DAAF-D5C7-4D1D-8382-54CA426A1BDC/cueLists",print_json)
    dispatcher.map("/update/workspace/C936DAAF-D5C7-4D1D-8382-54CA426A1BDC/cueList/*/playbackPosition",print_payload)
    dispatcher.map("/reply/cue_id/*/valuesForKeys", print_json)
    dispatcher.map("/reply/cue_id/*/valuesForKeys", print_name)


def start_server(ip, port):

    print("Starting Server")
    server = osc_server.ThreadingOSCUDPServer(
        (ip, port), dispatcher)
    print("Serving on {}".format(server.server_address))
    thread = threading.Thread(target=server.serve_forever)
    thread.start()

def start_client(ip, port):
    print("Starting Client")
    client = udp_client.SimpleUDPClient(ip, port)
    # print("Sending on {}".format(client.))
    thread = threading.Thread(target=get_workspace(client))
    thread2 = threading.Thread(target=print_active(client))
    thread.start()
    thread2.start()

# send random values between 0-1 to the three addresses
def get_workspace(client):
    client.send_message("/workspace/C936DAAF-D5C7-4D1D-8382-54CA426A1BDC/cueLists", 1)
    client.send_message("/workspace/C936DAAF-D5C7-4D1D-8382-54CA426A1BDC/updates", 1)

def print_active(client):
    while True:
        client.send_message("/cue/active/valuesForKeys", "[\"displayName\",\"number\", \"type\", \"isBroken\", "
                                                     "\"isLoaded\", \"isPaused\", \"isRunning\", \"preWait\", \"duration\", \"postWait\"]")
        time.sleep(1)


start_server(args.serverip, 53001)
start_client(args.clientip, 53000)
```

Script 2:
I copied the received JSON string of the workspace as variable. Then it builds a table using pyQt5. After hitting "R" it inserts a row for each received cue.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
import json


# var
cue_count = 1
cue_id = ""

# data
data = '{"status":"ok","data":[{"number":"","uniqueID":"0CBC2F3A-B4CB-46A0-AE74-0810598256AD","cues":' \
           '[{"number":"1","uniqueID":"C358F03C-128B-4BBA-B8D8-3E1C3D217775","flagged":false,' \
           '"listName":"Cue 1","type":"Memo","colorName":"none","name":"Cue 1","armed":true},' \
           '{"number":"2","uniqueID":"F2FDC19F-8E4F-43E6-B49F-BA421C886E63","flagged":false,' \
           '"listName":"Cue 2","type":"Memo","colorName":"none","name":"Cue 2","armed":true},' \
           '{"number":"3","uniqueID":"244B2654-51B3-4423-AF1A-6894F301CA6B","flagged":false,' \
           '"listName":"Cue 3","type":"Memo","colorName":"none","name":"Cue 3","armed":true},' \
           '{"number":"4","uniqueID":"42B37827-A5E8-444D-82D1-7706A8E197A6","flagged":false,' \
           '"listName":"Cue 4","type":"Memo","colorName":"none","name":"Cue 4","armed":true}],' \
           '"flagged":false,"listName":"Main Cue List","type":"Cue List","colorName":"none",' \
           '"name":"Main Cue List","armed":true}],"workspace_id":"C936DAAF-D5C7-4D1D-8382-54CA426A1BDC",' \
           '"address":"\/workspace\/C936DAAF-D5C7-4D1D-8382-54CA426A1BDC\/cueLists"}'


class TableFromList(QTableWidget):
    def __init__(self, data, *args):
        # Call parent constructor
        QTableWidget.__init__(self, *args)

        # Set the necessary configurations fot the table
        self.data = data
        self.resizeColumnsToContents()
        self.resizeRowsToContents()
        self.setColumnWidth(0, 100)
        self.setColumnWidth(0, 40)
        self.setColumnWidth(1, 200)
        self.setColumnWidth(2, 80)
        self.setColumnWidth(3, 80)
        self.setMinimumWidth(400)
        self.setWindowTitle("WORKSPACE")
        self.setSelectionBehavior(QAbstractItemView.SelectRows)
        self.setEditTriggers(QAbstractItemView.NoEditTriggers)
        self.setStyleSheet("color:white; background-color:black; font-weight: bold; selection-background-color: orange")
        self.setFont(QFont('Arial', 14))

        # Declare the variable to set the header content
        headers = ["No.", "NAME", "Armed"]

        # Set the header label of the table
        self.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(headers)

        # Read the particular cell value
        self.clicked.connect(self.on_click)
        self.currentItemChanged.connect(self.select_cue)

        # Display the window in the center of the screen
        win = self.frameGeometry()
        pos = QDesktopWidget().availableGeometry().center()
        win.moveCenter(pos)
        self.move(win.topLeft())
        self.show()

    def on_click(self):
        for ItemVal in self.selectedItems():
            # Read the header value based on the selected cell
            subject = self.horizontalHeaderItem(ItemVal.column()).text()
            # Print the detail information of the mark
            print("\n", self.ID_list[ItemVal.row()], " got ", ItemVal.text(), " in ", subject)

    def select_cue(self):
        global cue_id
        global data
        data_dict = json.loads(data)
        data_parsed = data_dict["data"][0]["cues"]
        value = self.currentRow()
        cue = self.item(value, 0)
        cue_number = cue.text()
        cue_number = int(cue_number) - 1
        cue_id = data_parsed[cue_number]["uniqueID"]
        print("ID: " + cue_id)
        print("Cue Number is: " + cue.text())

    def keyPressEvent(self, keyEvent):
        super(TableFromList, self).keyPressEvent(keyEvent)
        data = self.data

        def build_cuelist(data):
            data_dict = json.loads(data)
            cue_count = len(data_dict["data"][0]["cues"])
            data = data_dict["data"][0]["cues"]
            self.setRowCount(0)
            for i in range(cue_count):
                rowPosition = table.rowCount()
                table.insertRow(rowPosition)  # insert new row
                self.setItem(rowPosition, 0, QTableWidgetItem(str(data[i]["number"])))
                self.setItem(rowPosition, 1, QTableWidgetItem(str(data[i]["name"])))
                self.setItem(rowPosition, 2, QTableWidgetItem(str(data[i]["armed"])))
        if keyEvent.key() == Qt.Key_Return:
            print('*** Return pressed')
            print("OSC: /cue/" + cue_id + "/go")
        elif keyEvent.key() == Qt.Key_Enter:
            print('*** Enter pressed')
        elif keyEvent.key() == Qt.Key_1:
            print('*** 1 pressed')
        elif keyEvent.key() == Qt.Key_R:
            build_cuelist(self.data)


# Create app object and execute the app
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
table = TableFromList(data, 0, 3)
table.show()
app.exec()
```

Comment: Your question is unclear, could you explain me better

Comment: I want to combine both scripts into one working program. I guess i have to use threading or multithreading and read to some examples, but struggle to implement it here.

Comment: I understand that your goal is to combine but I don't understand what each script does. Could you explain in detail what they do since it seems that you have copied code. Does your first script work on its own? Since I see a lot of bad programming practices I am doubting that it will work.

Comment: Both scripts work. The first script uses example code from the pythons library. It opens  OSC (Open Sound Protocol) server and client. The client send out OSC messages to Qlab to which QLab responds with JSON strings. This way I'm able to get the whole workspace data ("/workspace/'ID'/cueLists", 1) and which cue is selected( update, 1). The while loop requests parameters of the currently active cue every second (just for testing).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code provided by the OP has various errors such as threads not being executed in a second thread, the code works because threads are not needed.

On the other hand, signals must be used to send the information from the callbacks to the widgets.

```py
import json
import sys
import threading
from dataclasses import dataclass
from functools import cached_property

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

from pythonosc import dispatcher
from pythonosc import osc_server
from pythonosc import udp_client


@dataclass
class Server(QtCore.QObject):
    ip: str = "127.0.0.1"
    port: int = 53001

    datachanged = QtCore.pyqtSignal(dict)

    def __post_init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    @cached_property
    def osc_server(self):
        dp = dispatcher.Dispatcher()
        dp.map(
            "/reply/workspace/C936DAAF-D5C7-4D1D-8382-54CA426A1BDC/cueLists",
            self.handle_reply_workspace,
        )
        dp.map(
            "/update/workspace/C936DAAF-D5C7-4D1D-8382-54CA426A1BDC/cueList/*/playbackPosition",
            self.handle_update_workspace,
        )
        dp.map(
            "/cue/active/valuesForKeys",
            self.handle_cue_id,
        )
        return osc_server.ThreadingOSCUDPServer((self.ip, self.port), dp)

    def start(self):
        threading.Thread(target=self.osc_server.serve_forever, daemon=True).start()

    def handle_reply_workspace(self, unused_addr, data):
        try:
            d = json.loads(data)
        except json.JSONDecodeError as e:
            print(str(e))
        else:
            self.datachanged.emit(d)

    def handle_update_workspace(self, unused_addr, data):
        print(data)

    def handle_cue_id(self, unused_addr, data):
        print(data)


@dataclass
class Client(QtCore.QObject):
    ip: str = "127.0.0.1"
    port: int = 53000

    datachanged = QtCore.pyqtSignal(dict)

    def __post_init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def start_timer(self, dt=1000):
        self.timer.start(dt)

    def request_workspace(self):
        self.osc_client.send_message(
            "/workspace/C936DAAF-D5C7-4D1D-8382-54CA426A1BDC/cueLists", 1
        )
        self.osc_client.send_message(
            "/workspace/C936DAAF-D5C7-4D1D-8382-54CA426A1BDC/updates", 1
        )

    @cached_property
    def osc_client(self):
        return udp_client.SimpleUDPClient(self.ip, self.port)

    @cached_property
    def timer(self):
        timer = QtCore.QTimer()
        timer.timeout.connect(self.handle_timeout)
        return timer

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def handle_timeout(self):
        keys = [
            "displayName",
            "number",
            "type",
            "isBroken",
            "isLoaded",
            "isPaused",
            "isRunning",
            "preWait",
            "duration",
            "postWait",
        ]
        self.osc_client.send_message(
            "/cue/active/valuesForKeys",
            json.dumps(keys),
        )


class TableWidget(QtWidgets.QTableWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setColumnCount(3)
        self.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(["No.", "NAME", "Armed"])

        self.setWindowTitle("WORKSPACE")
        self.setSelectionBehavior(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.SelectRows)
        self.setEditTriggers(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.NoEditTriggers)
        self.setStyleSheet(
            """
            color:white;
            background-color:black;
            font-weight: bold;
            selection-background-color: orange
            """
        )
        self.setFont(QtGui.QFont("Arial", 14))

        self.setColumnWidth(0, 40)
        self.setColumnWidth(1, 200)
        self.setColumnWidth(2, 80)
        self.setMinimumWidth(400)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(dict)
    def update_data(self, data):
        self.setRowCount(0)
        keys = ("number", "name", "armed")
        cues = data["data"][0]["cues"]
        for i, cue in enumerate(cues):
            self.insertRow(self.rowCount())
            for j, key in enumerate(keys):
                value = cue[key]
                item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
                item.setData(QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole, value)
                self.setItem(i, j, item)


def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    server = Server()
    server.start()

    client = Client()
    client.request_workspace()
    client.start_timer()

    table_widget = TableWidget()
    table_widget.resize(640, 480)
    table_widget.show()

    server.datachanged.connect(table_widget.update_data)

    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```